# Powershell: Start-Process output and Transcript

Tags: powershell, cmd

Example of the code:

```
$logfile = "log.txt"
$filename = "backup.rar"
Start-Transcript -Path $logfile -Append -Force
"Start..."
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" -ArgumentList ("a " + $filename + " @backup.lst") -NoNewWindow -Wait
"Done"
Stop-Transcript
```

Output in the console:

```
...
Start...
Error: Do not find backup.lst
Done
...
```

But in the log file:

```
...
Start...
Done
...
```

Where output Rar.exe?

PS: Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/315875/unable-to-capture-all-session-output-into-a-transcript) with `Start-Transcript` - it doesn't capture output from exes.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that the Start-Transaction is not capturing errors (obviously ;) )

You may want to look at using the start-process arguments of -RedirectStandardOutput and -RedirectStandardError

Comment: I think comments sections would be better place for this